# Adding a Color Picker/External Library to a jsPsych Plugin

Tags: javascript, html, jspsych

I am trying to create a [jsPsych](https://www.jspsych.org/) plugin where the user can select a color for each stimulus. For this I am using [jscolor](https://jscolor.com/). jscolor works well in vanilla HTML, but when I try to incorporate it in a jsPsych plugin it does not load the jscolor library.

```
jsPsych.plugins["color-picker"] = (function() {

var plugin = {};

plugin.info = {
  name: "color-picker",
  parameters: {
  }
}

plugin.trial = function(display_element, trial) {

  display_element.innerHTML += '<input data-jscolor="">'; // <-- This should show a color picker if jscolor.js is loaded.

  // data saving
  var trial_data = {
    parameter_name: 'parameter value'
  };

  // end trial
  jsPsych.finishTrial(trial_data);
};

return plugin;   })();
```

I don't understand why this exactly happens. Maybe I need to load the library inside the plugin? Adding `display_element.innerHTML += '<script src="library/jscolor.js"></script>';`  does not work either.

How can I implement this in my plugin?

Answer (score 0):

You can load the the `jscolor` library in your main experiment script and then reference the functions in the plugin.

One reason your plugin may not work right now is that the trial ends immediately after it begins because `jsPsych.finishTrial()` is called without waiting for any input from the user.

You'll likely want to move the `jsPsych.finishTrial()` call inside a function that is invoked based on the user submitting the form that includes the `jscolor` input element.